# Strongly-typed method decorations in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I have TypeScript code which listens to events based on topics, the topic generation is according to some specific context. I want to simplify the event registration code to use method decorators.

For example, I have a "Controller" which return a context for topic generation in event registration and an "@action" decorator which takes the context and returns a topic.

```
interface ContextProvider<T> {
  getContext(): T;
}

type MyContext = {
  some_id: number;
};

class Controller implements ContextProvider<MyContext> {
  @action(ctx => `event:${ctx.some_id}`)
  public eventHandler(message: any) {
    console.log("My event handler", message);
  }

  getContext(): MyContext {
    return { some_id: 6 };
  }
}
```

I did really simple decorator -

```
function action<TContext>(handler: (TContext) => void): Function {
  return function (object: object, aub, descriptor: any) {

    if(!object.hasOwnProperty("getContext")) {
      throw new Error("Can't bind @action to class which don't implement 'getContext' method");
    }

    // @ts-ignore
    const ctx = object.getContext();

    console.log(`listening to: ${handler(ctx)}`)
  };
}
```

As of today it works, but my problem comes with type-safety -

- `ctx` in handler is any instead of `MyContext` - I have a unit test that verifies the topic returns is correct, but I want to get auto-complete & compile time errors.
- I can put the `@action` on class that don't implements `ContextProvider` - it will crash on start-up time & when running unit tests with nice error message, but I want it to fail at compile time.

From what I observed and saw it looks there is no clear solution for this one, and I will need to have some repeated code, like

```
@action<MyContext>(ctx => `hello:${ctx.some_id}`)
```

Do you have any idea on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
type MyContext = {
  some_id: number;
};

// extra constraint
function action<TContext extends MyContext>(handler: (arg: TContext) => void): Function {
  return function (object: ContextProvider<MyContext>, aub: any, descriptor: any) {

    if (!object.hasOwnProperty("getContext")) {
      throw new Error("Can't bind @action to class which don't implement 'getContext' method");
    }

    // @ts-ignore
    const ctx = object.getContext();

    console.log(`listening to: ${handler(ctx)}`)
  };
}

interface ContextProvider<T> {
  getContext(): T;
}


class Controller implements ContextProvider<MyContext> {
  @action(ctx => `event:${ctx.some_id}`)
  public eventHandler(message: any) {
    console.log("My event handler", message);
  }

  getContext(): MyContext {
    return { some_id: 6 };
  }
}

//TEST


class Controller2 {
  @action(ctx => `event:${ctx.some_id}`) // error
  public eventHandler(message: any) {
    console.log("My event handler", message);
  }

}
```

Just use extra generic constraint for `action<TContext extends MyContext`

Comment: I have multiple classes which implements `ContextProvider` with different types of contexts, so I can tie the method decoration (action) to specific context type (if this was the case, the implementation here will be really simple). Take look here - https://gist.github.com/yosiat/486be3287e1bb7e8f84bcdb72a72643c, it still compiles :sob:

Comment: So, using decorator in class which not implements `COntextProvider` should trigger compiler error?

Comment: I made an update. You need to type `object` argument

Comment: `Controller2` throws compilation error on `@action` not getting generic type, so `@action<MyContext>` will work. Looks like there is no strong-typing in method decorators in typescript and I will need to model my requirements in different way. Thanks for helping out, appreciate it ~!